# XmlTextReader blocks application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I use `XmlTextReader` reader to get some data online.

During this stage application is like blocked.

I have tried to use `BeginInvoke` but it doesn't help a lots.

Or may be I need to implemented some kined of COMPLETED action....

I don't know...

Any clue how to resolve it?

Thank you!

```
var searchUrl = "http://weather.service.msn.com/find.aspx?outputview=search&src=vista&weasearchstr=" + query;
// Application is blocked here
var reader = new XmlTextReader(searchUrl);

while (reader.Read())
{
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using c# 5.0, async/await can help here

```
public async void SOQuestion(string query)
{
    var searchUrl = "http://weather.service.msn.com/find.aspx?outputview=search&src=vista&weasearchstr=" + query;

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    string xml = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(searchUrl);

    var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    var results = xDoc.Descendants("weather")
                        .Select(w => new
                        {
                            Location = w.Attribute("weatherlocationname").Value,
                            Temp = w.Element("current").Attribute("temperature").Value,
                            SkyText = w.Element("current").Attribute("skytext").Value,

                        })
                        .ToList();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = results;
}
```

Comment: @Peretz http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx or http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/introduction-to-async-and-await-keywords-in-c-5.0.htm

Comment: Have I use VS 2012 in order to use C#5.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

The TPL (Task Parallelization Library) is a nice and easy way to thread simple tasks like this. If you have a method for setting up the XMLReader and a method that you want to call afterwards it would look something like this:

```
Task XmlReaderTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadXmlUrl(url));
XmlReaderTask.ContinueWith(x => SometMethodToDoAfter());
```

It also doesn't require you to use C# 5.0 (I'm sure the new sync and await keywords are a better way of handling this) but TPL has been around for a while and is only getting better in the newer versions of .NET so for a a quick and easy intro to some basic threading its definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

You need use `Task<bool> ReadAsync()`

Comment: Thank you could u provide a little bit more info please by using my code?